# parsing xml with namespace from request with lxml in python

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I am trying to get some text out of a table from an online xml file. I can find the tables:

```
from lxml import etree
import requests

main_file = requests.get('https://training.gov.au/TrainingComponentFiles/CUA/CUAWRT601_R1.xml')
main_file.encoding = 'utf-8-sig'
root = etree.fromstring(main_file.content)
tables = root.xpath('//foo:table', namespaces={"foo": "http://www.authorit.com/xml/authorit"})

print(tables)
```

But I can't get any further than that. The text that I am looking for is:

1. Prepare to write scripts
2. Write draft scripts
3. Produce final scripts

When I paste the xml in here: http://xpather.com/

I can get it using the following expression:
`//table[1]/tr/td[@width="2700"]/p[@id="4"][not(*)]/text()`

but that doesn't work here and I'm out of ideas. How can I get that text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the namespace prefix you declared (with `namespaces={"foo": "http://www.authorit.com/xml/authorit"}`) e.g. instead of `//table[1]/tr/td[@width="2700"]/p[@id="4"][not(*)]/text()` use `//foo:table[1]/foo:tr/foo:td[@width="2700"]/foo:p[@id="4"][not(*)]/text()`.